# Why aren't there any 400V ultracapacitors?

Tags: high-voltage, supercapacitor, filtering

I thought that ulracaps could be better than electrolytic ones for filtering after a bridge rectifier in a compact switching power supply due to their higher energy density. But, for some reason, I can't find any high-voltage supercapacitors on ebay or amazon. I could, of course, put a bunch of low-voltage ultracapacitors in series but that would defeat the whole purpose of a power supply being compact. Is there any reason why there are no high-voltage supercapacitors? There already are 5.5V ultracapacitors, which are basically two 2.75V caps in series, so why they can't go higher? Did I miss something? Are they hard to manufacture?

Comment: They would be manufactured as you would do it yourself: put lots of them in series. The resulting product does not have much market value.

Comment: They'd be very expensive and no one would buy them.

Comment: eBay and Amazon are generally not good places to source electronic components. You have no tractability on the parts and generally no datasheet. "No datasheet? No sale!"

Answer (score 10):

A high-voltage super-capacitor/ultra-capacitor would be a contradiction in existing technologies. They achieve their high capacitive values by having a super thin dielectric of special materials, hence the low voltage limit.

To build a 400 volt capacitor means having a thicker 'solid' dielectric with more common materials, which 'fattens' up the size a lot.

There are large 450 volt electrolytic capacitors to 20,000 uF or more. To have a super-capacitor with the same voltage rating would be duplicating the large can-type electrolytics.

Super-capacitor/ultra-capacitors have been around a couple of decades now, mostly changing in materials to cut down on self-leakage. Graphene is the latest trend. The laws of physics and chemistry limit the size of such capacitors, or we would already have them to buy.

Engineers would love to have giant super-capacitors for cars, etc, so there is an on-going effort to reach that goal.

This is a snippet from [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercapacitor)

> A supercapacitor (SC) (also electric double-layer capacitor (EDLC),
>   also called supercap, ultracapacitor or Goldcap) is a high-capacity
>   capacitor with capacitance values much higher than other capacitors
>   (but lower voltage limits) that bridge the gap between electrolytic
>   capacitors and rechargeable batteries. They typically store 10 to 100
>   times more energy per unit volume or mass than electrolytic
>   capacitors, can accept and deliver charge much faster than batteries,
>   and tolerate many more charge and discharge cycles than rechargeable
>   batteries.
>
> Supercapacitors are used in applications requiring many rapid
>   charge/discharge cycles rather than long term compact energy storage:
>   within cars, buses, trains, cranes and elevators, where they are used
>   for regenerative braking, short-term energy storage or burst-mode
>   power delivery. Smaller units are used as memory backup for static
>   random-access memory (SRAM).
>
> Unlike ordinary capacitors, supercapacitors do not use the
>   conventional solid dielectric, but rather, they use electrostatic
>   double-layer capacitance and electrochemical pseudocapacitance, both
>   of which contribute to the total capacitance of the capacitor, with a
>   few differences:
>
> **Electrostatic double-layer capacitors** use carbon electrodes or
>   derivatives with much higher electrostatic double-layer capacitance
>   than electrochemical pseudocapacitance, achieving separation of charge
>   in a Helmholtz double layer at the interface between the surface of a
>   conductive electrode and an electrolyte. The separation of charge is
>   of the order of a few ångströms (0.3–0.8 nm), much smaller than in a
>   conventional capacitor.
>
> **Electrochemical pseudocapacitors** use metal
>   oxide or conducting polymer electrodes with a high amount of
>   electrochemical pseudocapacitance additional to the double-layer
>   capacitance. Pseudocapacitance is achieved by Faradaic electron
>   charge-transfer with redox reactions, intercalation or
>   electrosorption. Hybrid capacitors, such as the lithium-ion capacitor,
>   use electrodes with differing characteristics: one exhibiting mostly
>   electrostatic capacitance and the other mostly electrochemical
>   capacitance.

Comment: Your words and the quoted bits seem to disagree - if it was purely a dielectric thickness issue then they would have the same energy per unit volume as a normal capacitor, and the voltage could be adjusted by the thickness and/or putting them in series internally - yet they don't do that, they use all sorts of different technologies and the explanation of why such technologies like EDLC aren't configured for higher voltages (possibly because of the very low leakage currents that would lead to imbalances, which aren't as big of an issue for traditional capacitors)

Comment: @user2813274. Thanks for seeing that inadequate explanation. I have added a better definition of the various dielectrics.

Answer (score 5):

Supercapacitors are created by placing many, many layers of conductive plates and dielectric together in a package. In order to obtain a very high capacitance in a small amount of space, each plate must be spaced very close to one another (the dielectric must be extremely thin). The thickness of the dielectric is what limits the voltage levels in most cases. 400 volts can punch through thin dielectric very easily, rendering the capacitor useless. The low voltage is required to ensure the dielectric does not break down during use.

Comment: This sounds more like a description of film capacitors than supercapacitors.

Comment: @TimWilliams It applies to supercapacitors as well. In order to get high capacitance, by definition, you must have either a) a very wide area, b) very thin dielectric, c) many layers, or d) any combination of a, b, and c. Wide area is achieved by using many layers and thin dielectric regardless of capacitor type (film, MLCC, super, etc). My wording may have been confusing, however, as "many layers" does not necessarily mean "many layers in parallel", but instead two layers rolled around themselves over and over again into a cylinder. Either way, this answer remains valid

Answer (score 3):

It's really too bad that most of these answers are not accurate. Simply having an extremely thin dielectric is not actually how supercapacitors are made. This is in fact how electrolytic capacitors are made. One of the two conducting plates is made to form an ultrathin oxide layer, allowing the dielectric to be extremely thin. The main reason supercapacitors have low voltage is because of the break-down voltage of the electrolyte used in the capacitor, not its dielectric.

Comment: I suppose it depends on whether you are referring to electrostatic supercapacitors or electrochemical supercapacitors

Answer (score 0):

Supercapacitors/EDLC do not have a dielectric. To get more than about 3V you stack them in series to make a module. There are 400V and higher modules available, typically for electric buses/trucks following a regular route with recharging stations. They are quite large, so are only used when you don't want batteries (risk of explosion, short life) or ICE motors (polluting).

Supercapacitors are not electrostatic. There were some dielectric capacitors discussed that were very high voltage (>4000V) and so had high energy and were misleadingly called "super". These never came to commercialisation because they were a really stupid idea (10's of Wh at thousands of volts through a nano-thick ceramic dielectric). One defect in the dielectric and you get a very rapid discharge (aka explosion).

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to make one, by getting the electrolyte right, as Elliot Krueger said,  but 100 farads at 1000 volts?  Thats got to be deadly!  Maybe thats why they dont make them because they have live terminals after they are charged to their peak voltage.

Comment: Counter question: Why are there mains voltage outlets when their terminals are live and dangerous?